# llvm cmake add_llvm_loadable_module unknown

Tags: cmake, llvm

I am an llvm beginner. I compiled llvm which checked from svn, and I got the error: `unknown cmake command add_llvm_loadable_module` when using cmake to create a makefile in llvmroot/lib/Transform/Hello/build. I have no idea why this occur. Is there something wrong when compiling llvm? In this case, I compiled llvm by `cmake -G "Unix Makefiles"` in macros. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should pass LLVM root directory when calling CMake.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you tell me how to pass the LLVM root? If it should pass `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to CMake, I had try and the error still occurred.

Comment: Show full command line you are running. And in which directory.

Comment: I believe @arrowd refers to the `LLVM_DIR` in the `cmake` command line invocation.

Comment: Maybe you mean that I should pass the LLVM root to compile LLVM? Yes, of course I do, but I mean I got `unknown cmake command add_llvm_loader_module` when compiling the Hello example in lib/Transform.

Comment: I run the command `cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=~/llvm/build` in llvm_root/lib/Transform/Hello/build

Comment: that error means that the `cmake` files/modules that define that command are not found. why don't you post the full command-line invocation as @arrowd suggested in order to minimize the back and forth in the comments? *please amend the question by editing it*

Answer (score 0):

You just mixed things up.

You should `cd` into `~/llvm/build` and run `cmake ~/llvm` or `cmake ..`. And you don't need `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` at all in this case.

This command will just generate build files for you. Now, if you want to build only that Hello pass instead of whole LLVM, run `make help | grep Hello` to find out how the corresponding target is called and then `make <target>`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but my problem is not compiling LLVM. Compiling LLVM is success, but I got "Unknown Cmake command 'add_llvm_loadable_module' " when runing command `cmake .. ` in path "lib/Transform/Hello". And this  is an LLVM example of Pass.

Answer (score 0):

You should used add_llvm_library in CMakeLists.txt

like this:

```
add_llvm_library(My_Plugin MODULE My_Plugin.cpp PLUGIN_TOOL clang)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this as an answer (because not enough reputation to comment). Similar error on my end was fixed with:

```
add_library(HelloWorld SHARED HelloWorld.Cpp)
```

The solution was taken from [llvm tutor](https://github.com/banach-space/llvm-tutor) repository. For any llvm beginner, it is a codebase worth checking.